# What computational hardness concept corresponds to strongly-polynomial time algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, polynomial-time

Consider the computational problems in which the input is a set of $n$ integers with maximum magnitude $M$. According to [Erik Demaine's lecture notes](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/scribe/lec2.pdf), assuming $P\neq NP$, the following are true:

- If a problem is *strongly NP-hard*, then it does not have a *pseodupolynomial time algorithm* (an algorithm with run-time $\text{poly}(n,M)$).
- If a problem is *weakly NP-hard*, then it does not have a *weakly polynomial time algorithm* (an algorithm with run-time $\text{poly}(n,\log{M})$), but it may have a pseudopolynomial time algorithm.

Is there a hardness concept X such that, if a problem is "X hard", then it does not have a *strongly polynomial time algorithm* (an algorithm with run-time $\text{poly}(n)$), but it may have a weakly-polynomial time algorithm?

A related question: is there a natural problem for which it is proved that no strongly-polynomial-time algorithm exists (unless P=NP)?

Comment: Erik Demaine is being rather informal, or conversely, is working within the framework of computational geometry. There is only one notion of NP-hardness. "Weak NP-hardness" refers to NP-hardness when numbers are encoded in binary. "Strong NP-hardness" refers to NP-hardness when numbers are encoded in unary.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I partially agree with you. However, if we only consider the numbers encoded in binary then a "weak NP-hard" problem has a singly exponential algorithm in the input size, i.e., $2^{\log M}$, and a "strong NP-hard" does not have a singly exponential algorithm but some higher exponential algorithm is possible like $2^{2^{\log M}}$. Isn't there some complexity class for such distinction?

Comment: Standard complexity theory is only interested in a single parameter, namely the size of the input. Parameterized complexity also cares about other parameters, so perhaps that's the proper place to look.